# Angular 2 - when to put service in component's provider vs in a module?

Tags: angular

I am confused about when to put a service into the component's provider in `@Component()` vs into a `NgModule()`

For example, if I have a service that is going to make HTTP calls to get links for my FooterComponent, then should that go into the app's `NgModule` or should it be used as a `provider` in the FooterComponent's `@Component`?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you want to use the service. If you want to use different instances of service in different objects of component class you should provide it in @Component. If you want to use one instance in different objects you should provide it in @NgModule.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the providers in the NgModule because I might have to provide a custom value to the component and in that case I can overwrite the value in the NgModule with a provide in the component or directive.

Also it's way less work to go through a couple modules instead of a lot of components when for example refactoring.

I couldn't find any official guidelines about this subject however.